# Printing text - Pygame

Tags: python, text, io, pygame

I am wondering how it might be possible to print text using pygame, currently I have this code (which I thought would work but doesnt):

```
for player in player_list:

    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, True)

    for block in block_hit_list:
        health -= 25
        collision.play()

        if health == 0:
            font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 30)
            label = font.render("GAME OVER", 1, (255,100,0))
            screen.blit(label, (400, 300))
            break


    if health == 0:
        gameover.play()
        collision.stop()
        player_list.remove(player)
        all_sprites_list.remove(player)
        block_list.remove(block)
        all_sprites_list.remove(block)
```

Im not sure why it isnt printing, if anyone has any suggestions Id appreciate the help!

Comment: Can we see the rest of your code/a [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Michael0x2a Updated, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
labelRect = label.get_rect()
labelRect.center = (400, 300)
```

under the line that says `label = font.render...`

Then, replace the `screen.blit` line with:

```
screen.blit(label, labelRect)
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply :) I tried your suggestion but unfortunately still no text is displayed, I have updated the code above to show the surrounding lines (In case this helps at all?) I am quite new to python so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: thanks for your reply again, I've applied the suggested changes but still no text gets printed :( I really don't know why this is, but here's my full code in case I am making an obvious/ silly mistake: http://pastebin.com/T7NRxdEW

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on your question yet, I have to make it an answer already. Could you please provide the entire code, especially the part where your display is updated? I'm almost 100% sure that you blit the text, then fill the screen and blit the rest of the game, so the text actually is blitted but then covered by the fill and other blittings.

But like this I can't help you. The way you do it should work.

Comment: Sure, ive uploaded the entire code here: http://pastebin.com/T7NRxdEW thanks for your reply and I apologise if I have made any silly mistakes, Im quite new to python

Comment: I only had a quick glance at it as I'm in a hurry right now, but seems I was right with my analysis: You seem to blit the test in the health == 0 section, then you update the screen, blitting the background over it. Put the blitting of the Game-over text after you have screen.blit(background, (0,0).
To prevent errors put it this way:
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    if label != None:
        screen.blit(label, labelRect)

and add a label = None at the beginning where you define your variables.
As a "general rule": Put everything to blit in one list and do the blitting once by this list